# Replace exact word with an optional letter prefix

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace the word `PARAM_DATETIME` in the string:

```
 string input = "^FT734,274^A0I,28,28^FH\\^FDPARAM_DATETIME^FS";
```

I'm trying with:

```
string newstr = Regex.Replace("^FT734,274^A0I,28,28^FH\\^FDPARAM_DATETIME^FS", @"\bPARAM_DATETIME\b", "27-01-2022");
```

but it doesn´t work.

The goal is to match the word `PARAM_DATETIME` even if it is preceded with `F` at the start of the word followed with any uppercase letter.

Comment: What happened when you tried without the word boundary anchors (`\b`) before and after the string?

Comment: is it always `PARAM_DATETIME` ? no variations of it? if yes then I don't see any necessity for regex here. Can you post the expected result?

Comment: The regex you doesnt work because of the word boundaries. ie: In your input 'D' preceeds PARAM_DATETIME, this causes the first `\b` to not match your input. The regex will match your input if you remove \b and re write it as: `@"PARAM_DATETIME\b"`

Comment: Maybe you want `Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=\\\^F[A-Z]|\b)PARAM_DATETIME\b", "27-01-2022")`? Or, `Regex.Replace(text, @"\b(F[A-Z])?PARAM_DATETIME\b", "${1}27-01-2022")`? Please clarify what you actually are trying to achieve.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yess the second option works as I need, thank you!

Comment: @AlbertoIbernón Great, I posted an [answer with explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70878371/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
Regex.Replace(text, @"\b(F[A-Z])?PARAM_DATETIME\b", "${1}27-01-2022")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U5QCY9/1). *Details*:

- `\b`  - a word boundary
- `(F[A-Z])?` - Group 1 (optional): `F` and then any one ASCII uppercase letter
- `PARAM_DATETIME` - a word
- `\b`  - a word boundary

The match is replaced with Group 1 value (`${1}`) and the hardcoded string.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to change the word `PARAM_DATETIME`, isn't it easier to use [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0)?

```
string input = "^FT734,274^A0I,28,28^FH\\^FDPARAM_DATETIME^FS";
input = input.Replace("PARAM_DATETIME", "27-01-2022");
```

Comment: yes, but the problem is that If I have another parameter called PARAM_DATE then it will replace also with the result "27-01-2022TIME"

Comment: @AlbertoIbernón why should it? it will try to match the entire word: "PARAM_DATETIME". This would happen is you have something that is longer like `PARAM_DATETIME_DontReplace`.

Comment: @AlbertoIbernón that won't happen, since the string has to be `PARAM_DATETIME`. So it won't see `PARAM_DATE`. And like Mong Zhu said, it might find strings that are longer.